# Appending Ajax results to respective elements

Tags: jquery

I have some elements which creates some elements and append its results to its respective div

```
<a onclick="popUp('1')">user 1</a>
<a onclick="popUp('2')">user 2</a>
<a onclick="popUp('3')">user 3</a>

function popUp(id){
    $el = $('<div>').attr({
        id:id,
        'class' : 'popDiv' 
    })
    if($('body').append($el)){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/link.php?user='+id, 
            success : function(data) {
              $el.html(data);
            }
        }) 
    } 
}
```

But the issue is that if I click user 1 and the success data hasn't returned before I click user 2. If the user 1 data returns, it will be appended to the created element of user 2 instead of user 1.

Is there a way I can correct this

Comment: in this case if condition seems odd to me. you can remove it. and at every click it calls same function and creates a new div element, so it seems odd if it gets same div, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Even if I remove the if condition,  it's still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick version without ajax:

```
var fns = [],
calls = 0;

function popUp(id) {
    var $el = $('<div>').attr({
        id: id,
        'class': 'popDiv'
    });


    if ($('body').append($el)) {
        var i = fns.push({
            fn: function(data) {
                $el.html(data);
            }
        }) - 1;
        calls++;
        ajax({
            url: '/link.php?user=' + id,
            success: function(data) {
                fns[i].data = data;
                calls--;
                if (!calls) {
                    fns.forEach(function(it) {
                        console.log(it);
                        it.fn(it.data);
                    })
                    fns = [];
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

function ajax(data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        data.success("Response " + data.url);
    }, parseInt(Math.random(0, 1) * 4) * 1000 + 1000);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/yaxfcq46/

Answer (score 0):

You can try and disable the links on click (for example by setting their css to position:relative and negative z-index) and then enable them when data is returned. Alternatively you can use buttons and add/remove disabled attributes.

Comment: I don't want to have such because I want my users to be able to click multiple links so quickly